# Type not accesible in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

I'm trying to create a web service based on Java EE with Apache Axis and Tomcat. When I used the wizard to create a server based on WSDL file, eclipse created *http.base.jsp* and the line that import Axis servlet:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet" %>
```

This generates the following error:

> The type org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet is not accessible

I'm looking for information about the solution on internet and I had been trying those that have sense for me, like to charge the package manually or update it, but the type remains unaccessible.

I'm using Java 11, Eclipse Enterprise edition 2020 y Axis2 1.7.9

Comment: Does your project contain a `module-info.java`?

Comment: Yes, it contains a `module-info.java`

Comment: Try either deleting it (so your project isn't using the Java Module System), or making sure that the axis library is listed in it.

Comment: Axis library was listed in module-info.java, so I deleted it, but the error is still there. Thanks for replying. Maybe do you have other idea for solve it?

Comment: I meant, try deleting the entire module-info.java.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly as I did